# XSLT use blank lines

Tags: xml, windows, xslt, ms-word, word-2003

I have the following XML:

```
<node><mtype>code</mtype><mtext>&lt;script&gt;
 // a Javascript example
 alert("Hello World");
 &lt;/script&gt;</mtext></node>
```

The same text in HTML would be written as follows:

```
<pre><code>&lt;script&gt;
 // a Javascript example
 alert("Hello World");
 &lt;/script&gt;</code></pre>
```

We can see that the actual text is HTML encoded, which is fine. What I want to do next is use the following XSLT to represent the above mtext as the `<code>` element in Word XML (with a specific style).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml"
  >

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/node">
    <xsl:if test="mtype = 'code'">
      <w:p>
        <w:pPr><w:jc w:val="left" /></w:pPr>
        <!--<xsl:text select="mtext/node()"/>-->
        <w:r><w:t><xsl:value-of select="mtext/node()" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></w:t></w:r>
      </w:p>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If I run the XLST agains the defined XML I get the following:

```
$ xsltproc code.xslt code.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<w:p xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="left"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t><script>
 // a Javascript example
 alert("Hello World");
 </script></w:t></w:r></w:p>
```

This isn't what I would like to achieve. The first thing are the actual special characters and the more important thing are the new lines that are stipped. Whatever I use in the `<w:t>` element is visible in one line only, but my `<code>` text has multiple lines, which is why I also need multiple lines.

I've heard that I could use `<xsl:text>` or `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>`, but I wasn't able to produce the XML that would actually create the **multiline** `<code>` sections in Microsoft Word.

Edited: Jakob, if I uses that I got no newlines. The ending XML is as follows, which doesn't print newlines:

```
<w:p wsp:rsidR="005963F5" wsp:rsidRDefault="00804A03" wsp:rsidP="00804A03" xml:space="preserve">
<w:pPr><w:jc w:val="left"/><w:pStyle w:val="VirisCode"/></w:pPr>
<w:r><w:t>
     &lt;script&gt;
     // a Javascript example
     alert("Hello World");
     &lt;/script&gt;
 </w:t></w:r>
</w:p>
```

**Comment:** I DON'T KNOW what the output should look like, since I'm not the XML guru; if I knew that I would probably be able to write that myself. So the XML can look whatever it likes as long as it works. By works I mean that it displays the `<code>` blocks the way I want. I want the code blocks to be displayed exactly as they appear in the `<mtext>` XML node, with the new lines and everything. In this case the exact output (once already opened with Word) should show the following:

```
<script>
// a Javascript example
alert("Hello World");
</script>
```

Note that the special characters are displayed correctly and the newlines are present. The problem is with the `<w:t>` element that displays everything in one line, which is what I don't want, but don't know what else to use.

Comment: Please, *edit* the question and provide the exact transformation result you want to get.

Comment: @Administrator, you need to update your question with "RESULT XML" you are expecting! Though you couldn't achieve what you wanted to.. `type it manually what you want output to be like` that gives easier idea to us in understanding the question .. rather than reading through complicated lines..

Comment: I've updated the answer. I appologise in advance for not knowing what the XML should look like, but that is why I asked the question. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

use the xml:space on the xsl:output, template, element or value-of lvl for preserving newlines/space.

Comment: Hi, This isn't working for w:t elements, so I need a different solution. Maybe the one that isn't using w:t elements?

Comment: use the xsl:output xml:space="preserve" located in top for those ?

Comment: Hi, yes I've also tried there with no change; the new lines are still not shown

Comment: Hi, if you have any other idea, please share it with me, I'm still stuck. Thank you.